# VBA Run-time error: '9'

Tags: excel, vba, runtime-error

I am trying to create a a function that takes some inputs of selected position and day and then using the day input, scan the matching sheet for data. However, passing a string to Sheets.Activate is causing me to get

> runtime error 9

I am not sure why this is happening as other people did this in similar solutions on stack overflow. Here is my code

```
Sub GatherNames()

Dim x As Integer
Dim y As Integer
Dim rowN As Integer
Dim cell As String
Dim day As String
Dim position As String

day = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Coverage").Range("C3")

Sheets(day).Activate

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

'Acquire entire data range
NumRows = Range("B3", Range("B3").End(xlDown)).Rows.Count
NumRows = NumRows / 2
'Start at beginning of data
rowN = 3
cell = "B" & rowN
Range(cell).Select
'Run for loop to check all rows
For y = 1 To NumRows
    'Get Rows Value
    Range(cell).End(xlToRight).Select

    'Add to list
    If (ActiveCell.Value > 1) Then
        Debug.Print ActiveCell.Value
    End If

    'Reset Cell to beginning of next Row
    rowN = rowN + 2
    cell = "B" & rowN
    Range(cell).Select
Next
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

I have tested all the code while excluding grabbing the day and then activating the day sheet and it works fine, but when I try and take in a string and then go to that sheet using

```
Sheets(day).Activate
```

it causes

> run time error 9 - subscript out of range

For extra detail, the value of day is "Monday" and I have a sheet called Monday.

Comment: You should reference your ranges to allocated worksheets such as `ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Coverage").Range("B3")`. Using `select` or `activate` is not a good practice.

Comment: Double check that there are no spaces in the cell or the name of the sheet.

Comment: Checked for spaces, there are none. And Tehscript the reason im doing this is because once I added grabbing the value for day, the rest of the code worked off of that sheet giving me useless data instead of using one of the weekday sheets. How can I get around this?

Comment: Well, for some reason excel is not finding the sheet by the name you provide in that cell.  Without seeing your actual workbook, there is no way for use to find the issue.  Try copying the name of the sheet and pasting directly into the cell and see if that works.  Again we are only guessing.

Comment: after the line `day = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Coverage").Range("C3")` add a line: `msgbox "--" & day & "--"`  .  What does it say when you run the code again?

Comment: @ScottCraner It worked by simply writing it. I'll be able to figure out what I messed up now that I know the exact problem thank you!

Answer (score 1):

**`Day`** is a Reserved Word so you can't use it as a variable.  Change all references to that variable to something else, like ***`myDay`***.

In the VB Editor, press <kbd>F2</kbd> to open the Object Browser:  basically *none* of the listed should be used for naming objects/variables/sheets/etc, as they are **reserved** for VBA.

If you're still having a problem, try, on the modified line (using ***`myDay`*** for example), after this:

```
myDay = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Coverage").Range("C3")
```

...add a line:

```
MsgBox "--" ActiveSheet.Name & "--" & vbcrlf & "--" & myDay& "--"
```

What does it say when you run the code again?

- Are the 2 lines identical?
- If you get an error, please include the full text or a screenshot of the error and where it is breaking the code.